# Can I route traffic from internet to a router to a raspberry pi to another raspberry pi?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I'm not sure if what I am trying to do is even possible or what to even search for. I bought 2 raspberry pi's to replace my current setup.

Old setup:
Desktop running plex and tautulli, ssh
Laptop running sonarr, radarr, Jackett, and Deluge, ssh and VPN
* If I lose connection on laptop and I am not home I have to ssh into desktop and then ssh into laptop to reset connection

New set up:
I have 2 raspberry Pi's (rpi1 and rpi2)

Rpi1 Running:
VPN
-Deluge
-Jackett

Rpi2 Running:
Sonarr
Radarr

I want to be able to access rpi1 from the internet not just locally, but I want to route the traffic through rpi2 so only have to open ports to rpi2 I guess similar to a tunnel

Outside Device
\
 -Router --------------
    |                           \
  RPI2 - Sonarr         \
     |     - Radarr          \
     |                             Rest of Network
       - RPI1 - Deluge
                   - Jackett

So if I went to 10.0.0.5:5000 on RPi2 it would actually be 10.0.0.4:5000 on RPi1 or rpi2.net:5000 for remote access still takes me to 10.0.0.4:5000

Any help or thoughts be greatly appreciated